# Ubuntu Dualboot partitioning: cant choose windows mount point

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, partitioning, lubuntu

I am at the moment trying to install lubuntu 16.04 on my fathers Laptop as dualboot alongside with Windows 10. The Laptop got a 1TB Hardrive with two partitions: A big one and a small one with about 25GB (I think with recovery stuff). I booted lubuntu as live-system from DVD and started the installation. Unfortunately when I chose to install lubuntu alongside with Win10 it chooses the small partition. So I followed this guide: [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation/343370#343370)
The Problem is step 4. when I choose the large partition I cant chose /windows as mount point like in the picture. What should I do now? I am a bit worried that I damage Windows when I continue without chosing windows as mount point.

Comment: The step of assigning a mount point to the Windows partition is completely optional, but since you've asked, why can't you? What's wrong? What are the errors, if any?

Comment: so when i shrink the windows partition without setting a mount point it wont damage my windows installation? I am worried that i will take parts of the partition that are occupied by windows.

Comment: Well, assigning a mount point won't damage Windows for sure, but shrinking its partition actually might go wrong. Then of course, those are two different things. The `/windows` is simply there to show how to assign a mount point manually. Last, but not least, it is advised in one of the answers to shrink Windows partitions from Windows, which is a good idea.